# Segmentation fault in tokenizing c block

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to pointers and such. This function is supposed to take a character array and split it into component words, except where there is quotes (then everything in quotes is kept together).

Prior to adding support for quotes, it worked perfectly, but now I get segmentation faults.

```
int parse(char *line, char **args) {
    int argc = 0;

    while ( *line != '\0' ) {
        if ( *line == '\'' || *line == '\"' ) {
            *args++ = line;
            ++argc; ++line;

            while ( *line != '\'' || *line != '\"' )
                ++line;

            ++line;
        }
        else {
            while ( *line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n' )
                *line++ = '\0';

            *args++ = line;
            ++argc;

            while ( *line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n' )
                    ++line;
        }
    }

    *--args = '\0';

    return --argc;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you call this function? What variables (and their declaration/definition/initialization) do you pass to the function? Can you please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also, have you tried running in a debugger?It will stop when and where the crash happens, and let you examine variables and the call stack. If the crash is not in your code, you walk up the call stack until you are at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your interior loops over `line` are flawed, as the don't check for the end of the string. This means that if there is no end quote in the string, you will go beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Balanced quotes are a precondition.

Comment: @user3525381 But it appears that your code considers `'this"` to be balanced quotes... Also, `'` could be an apostrophe instead of a quote, in which case you need to check context to avoid having to balance it...

Comment: Also acceptable. This is just for a homework assignment in one of my CS classes, and part of the instructions include that quotes will be balanced, symmetrical, etc. I just need to be able to keep together any phrases marked with double or single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to give you problems

```
       while ( *line != '\'' || *line != '\"' )
            ++line;
```

without

```
  || *line != 0
```